# Cannot find control of dynamically generated textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam generating dynamic textbox in rowData bound as follows,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
       {  
           try  
           {  
               if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
               { 
                   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; colIndex++)  
                   {  
                           int rowIndex = colIndex;
                           TextBox txtName = new TextBox();  
                           txtName.Width = 16; 
                           txtName.AutoPostBack = true;  
                           txtName.ID="txtName"
                           e.Row.Cells[colIndex].Controls.Add(txtName); 

                       }  
                   }  
               }  

           }  
           catch (Exception ex)  
           {  
           }  

       }
```

on button click event i want to find control of that textbox as below,

```
foreach (GridViewRow rows in GridView1.Rows)
 {
      TextBox txtName= (TextBox)rows.FindControl("txtName");

      string test= txtName.Text;

 }
```

But above code return null.
When I try to find control of dynamic textbox on button click event it returns null please help..

Comment: But you didnt call either of them txtName.. one is txtboxname+number, the other txtboxname1+number (which could cause an issue if you have more than 10...

Comment: only one texbox i have used..

Comment: Well it doesnt help you changed your code post since I made the comment.. originally yoou had  ID=txtboxname+ a number, and another txt box with txtboxname1+number...   in the current code you have not named your box at all

Comment: yes I have edited the code the above  code  I have set Textbox ID already  but i cannot findcontrol in button click event

Comment: But the names you given it each time are not the name you searched on! currently the name is txt_size not txtName

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the name:

```
txtName.Name = "txtName";    // or txtName.Name = "whatever";
```

Comment: I have edited my code i have set textbox ID but still I cannot findcontrol textbox in button click event